# How can I assign the vetical line to my HP EliteBook keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, characters

The keyboard of my new laptop is smaller than my last, with no number pad, meaning I'm having to find alternatives to ASCII codes for some of the special characters. One I can't seem to manage is the vertical line (Alt+0124). It's pictured on my keyboard under the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, activated with the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key, but using it creates this: `¦`, and not the solid vertical line.

Does anyone know how if I can reassign the correct character for that key? Or if there's an alternative to the ASCII code that works online, for example, while editing Fandom wikias?

EDIT: It's a HP EliteBook 84 G3. I've been using UK layout keyboard, but switching to US doesn't make a difference with this.

Comment: Nearly every keyboard (US layout keyboard that is) has ascii 124 | as Shift-\. Some fonts display it with the same symbol as ¦ though. Please specify which model Elitebook (there exist dozens with different keyboard layouts) and which language keyboard you have (you can edit that in your question).

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Try <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.